# PHP PDO Crud advice

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have just started to learn PDO and have managed to do simple CRUD operations on one single table.

I am just doing a SELECT * from the table. But this table has a foreign key to another table, and I would rather show the value on that column instead of a ID.

So my table structure is the following. I have a joke table with id and joketext and a foreign key authorId. The author table has authorId and name for the author.

Instead of doing SELECT * on the joke table, I would rather create a view with the following code:

```
SELECT
joke.joketext,
author.name
FROM
author
INNER JOIN joke
 ON author.id = joke.authorid
```

But for the CRUD operations I would like to show the author.name in a dropdown instead, so the users don't erroneously put in wrong values.

This is how index.php looks like:

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
$result = $dbConn->query("SELECT * FROM joke ORDER BY id DESC");
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="add.html">Add New Data</a><br/><br/>

    <table width='80%' border=0>

    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td>Joke</td>
        <td>AuthorId</td>
        <td>Update</td>
    </tr>
    <?php     
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['joketext']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['authorid']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$row[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";        
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```

and my edit file looks like this:

```
<?php
// including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{    
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $name=$_POST['joketext'];
    $authorid=$_POST['authorid']; 

    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($joketext) || empty($authorid)) {    

        if(empty($joketext)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($authorid)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Author field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }


    } else {    
        //updating the table
        $sql = "UPDATE joke SET joke=:joketext, authorid=:authorid WHERE id=:id";
        $query = $dbConn->prepare($sql);

        $query->bindparam(':id', $id);
        $query->bindparam(':joketext', $joketext);
        $query->bindparam(':authorid', $authorid);
        $query->execute();

        // Alternative to above bindparam and execute
        // $query->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':name' => $name, ':email' => $email, ':age' => $age));

        //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
?>
<?php
//getting id from url
$id = $_GET['id'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM joke WHERE id=:id";
$query = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':id' => $id));

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $joketext = $row['joketext'];
    $authorid = $row['authorid'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <br/><br/>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Joke</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="joketext" value="<?php echo $joketext;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Author</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="authorid" value="<?php echo $authorid;?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Can someone show me a hint on at least the edit operations how the php code would like?

thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it a problem with your query or the UI? Can you clarify what behavior you're expecting and what behavior you're getting?

Comment: sorry, just updated my question

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but can you give the query selects aliases like `joke.joketext as joketext, author.name as authorname` and then use authorname in index.php where you have `authorid`? If so I will post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to provide a select element of available authors for the user to choose from on the edit page, rather than have them enter an ID number for an author, then you can select all the authors from the database and loop through them, building the options of your select element. A select element can show the user the name of the author, but pass the ID of the author back to the server. You can also pre-select an author to show the user the currently associated author by default and they only have to change it if it's wrong.

So first, select all the authors from the database:

```
$authorSql = 'SELECT * FROM author';
$authorQuery = $dbConn->prepare($authorSql);
$authorQuery->execute();
```

Then use that data to build a select element:

```
<select name="authorid">
<?php
    while($author = $authorQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if ($author['id'] == $authorid) {
            //The author is currently associated to the joke, select it by default
            echo "<option value=\"{$author['id']}\" selected>{$author['name']}</option>";
        } else {
            //The author is not currently associated to the joke
            echo "<option value=\"{$author['id']}\">{$author['name']}</option>";
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

The output might look something like this:

```
<select name="authorid">
    <option value="1">George Carlin</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Richard Pryor</option>
    <option value="3">Don Rickles</option>
</select>
```

Whatever option the user selects, they'll see on the page what is between the `<option></option>` tags, but the form will pass the value of the `value` property to the server as the `authorid` parameter.

The code that generates the select element replaces the `<input type="text" name="authorid" value="<?php echo $authorid;?>">` and remains within the `<td></td>` tags.

Hope I managed to address your actual need, let me know if I missed the intent of your question.

Note: my code isn't tested, so some adjustment may be required.

---

**EDIT #1:** Fixed incorrect variable names.

Comment: First I got a error, then I changed $authorQuery = $dbConn->prepare($sql); to $authorQuery = $dbConn->prepare($authorSql; The page loads without error but with a empty dropdown, I have rechecked the table for proper column names, just to be sure and its id and name in the author table.

Comment: If the select element renders but there are not options within it, then my guess at the most likely issue is that the `SELECT * FROM author` is not returning any rows. Before the `while` statement line, add `echo $authorQuery->rowCount();` - that will tell you how many rows were returned by the PDO statement (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Comment: A note on my previous comment: it will print the number within the `select` element if you put it right above the `while`, so you won't see anything on the page - instead view the source of the page and find the `select` statement. Alternatively, put it right after `$authorQuery->execute();`

Comment: it pasted it on both places, its showing 5, and thats the actual row count of the author table, but if I take a look at the inspector, for each option its giving me this: 
5
Notice:  Undefined variable: authorid in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ijdb_pdo/edit1.php on line 26

Notice:  Undefined variable: row in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ijdb_pdo/edit1.php on line 31

Notice:  Undefined variable: row in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ijdb_pdo/edit1.php on line 31

Comment: That's odd, I thought `$authorid` was defined above where it reads `$authorid = $row['authorid'];`. Was `$authorid` printing a value before you replaced the input element with the select element?

Comment: yes, it is in a different file. the edit.php file but its not defined anywhere in this current file I am experimenting with.

Comment: Ah, well that would explain it then - I assumed the edit.php file was what you were working in. If need more help we should take this into a chat instead of continuing in the comments.

Comment: thanks, that would be helpful :) can we Skype?Then I could share my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141392/discussion-between-stratedge-and-user2371684).